Get access token for FCM using Google.Apis.Auth version 1.14.1.0
In my company, there is a job scheduler that handles a couple of background jobs. I have a Firebase push notification service that is managed by this job scheduler. Recently, we had to migrate from the legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1. I successfully completed the migration, but I later realized that the job scheduler is using older versions of Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Auth, and Google.Apis.Core (1.14.1.0). However, I used the latest version (1.68.0.0), which is not compatible with the job scheduler. The company does not allow updates to the job scheduler at this time. My problem lies with the following method that creates the token.
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    GoogleCredential credential;
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourceName = "Peo.Mobile.Resources.firebase_json.json";
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            await WriteLogAsync("Embedded resource not found.");
            return null;
        }
        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
            .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");
    }
    var accessToken = await credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
    return accessToken;
}

Older versions does not have this UnderlyingCredential. I don't know how to create the token from older versions.
